# jqPlot show percent and value on pie chart

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I'm using jqPlot with jqplot.PieRenderer to try and display a pie chart. On the label I'd like to show `value (percent)`. The documentation says you can pass `dataLabel` an array of label types [(source)](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-pieRenderer-js.html#$.jqplot.PieRenderer.dataLabels), however, putting `%d%%` (for percent) and `%d` (for value) in the `dataLabelFormatString` option end up showing nothing.

Any ideas here?

```
{ 
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer, 
        rendererOptions: {
            showDataLabels: true,
            dataLabels: ['value', 'percent'],
            dataLabelFormatString: "%d %d%%",
            sliceMargin: 4,
            fill: false
        }
    }, 
    legend: { show:true, location: 'e' }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I read those docs a little differently.  It's the options 'value', 'percent', 'label' OR an array of labels.  Not an array of options.  To do what you want you'll need to create your datalabels as a real array of labels.

For example:

```
data = [
    ['Heavy Industry', 12],['Retail', 9], ['Light Industry', 14], 
    ['Out of home', 16],['Commuting', 7], ['Orientation', 9]
];

var total = 0;
$(data).map(function(){total += this[1];})

myLabels = $.makeArray($(data).map(function(){return this[1] + " " + Math.round(this[1]/total * 100) + "%";}));
```

See example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/dFgGj/).

Comment: Thank you very much! I wish I could give you more than one rep for this.

Comment: Excellent - I also got a little confused with the docs and tried implementing an array of options - you solved it - Super thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 formatter: function(label, series){
                        return '<div style="font-size:14pt;text-align:center;padding:2px;color:white;">'+Math.round(series.percent)+"%<br/>" + series.data[0][1] +'</div>';
                    },
```